# How do you install XR Interaction Toolkit in Unity 2021.3?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

Neither of these work:

- Installing by name: com.unity.xr.interaction.toolkit
- Installing by registry preview.

Comment: Tested in Unity 2021.3.1f1 -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQ4eC.png

Comment: I think its an LTS issue.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is Unity's own native plugin but it is not listed in `Window-PackageManager-UnityRegistry` because it is still in preview. This works for pre-2021 releases. Click on `Advanced Project Settings`

[image]

`Enable Preview Packages` then confirm it:

[image]

Now back to Package Manager, `XR Interaction Toolkit` should be in the list:

[image]

- You could also add the package with `Add package from git url` using `com.unity.xr.interaction.toolkit`

[image]

Comment: This is a good answer, but it's dependent on the version of Unity.  This won't work in 2021 LTS.

Comment: @place-wide you are correct. I just installed 2022 release but first method did not work. but using install from git method worked

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with running the LTS version of Unity.  As soon as I switched to 2022.1 (non-LTS) the package showed up without even manually typing the name.